# SQL Server - Alternative to Exists (too many subqueries)

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I'm looking for a way to improve performance of a query that has too many exists linked subqueries.

My problem is that I have a Orders Detail table where, for each ítem of the order, has a certain category (stored in another table, but that is irrelevant now).

I have to detect a particular "group" of orders based on different combinations of that categories: 
 - Group A: Orders with ítems on categories 13 + 15 + any of (66, 67, 68, 69)
            Orders with ítems on categories 77 + 78 + any of (66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 71)

What I've done so far is HUGE query with linked exists to find the orders that meet that criteria, but it is a performance nightmare.

I hope there's a better way to do this, because my table has millions of records...

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You query is broad and not clear to me  please update  your question and add  a proper data sample  .. the expected  result and a sample of your code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `group by` and `having`:

```
select order_id
from order_details od
group by order_id
having sum(case when category = 13 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- at least one 13
       sum(case when category = 15 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- at least one 15
       sum(case when category in (66, 67, 68, 69) then 1 else 0 end) > 0  -- at least one of these
```

This can easily be extended.  So for the second group:

```
having (sum(case when category = 13 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- at least one 13
        sum(case when category = 15 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- at least one 15
        sum(case when category in (66, 67, 68, 69) then 1 else 0 end) > 0    
       ) or
       (sum(case when category = 77 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- at least one 13
        sum(case when category = 78 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- at least one 15
        sum(case when category in (66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 71) then 1 else 0 end) > 0    
       )
```

Comment: I've done a quick test and it looks like it works like a charm, easy and incredibly fast!!!  Thanks a lot for your help and creative solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how your database is structured but you might try something similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       orders.order_id AS group_a_order
FROM   orders
JOIN   order_details od13
  ON   orders.order_id = od13.order_id
 AND   od13.category = 13
JOIN   order_details od15
  ON   orders.order_id = od15.order_id
 AND   od15.category = 15
JOIN   order_details od6x
  ON   orders.order_id = od6x.order_id
 AND   od6x.category IN (66, 67, 68, 69)
```

This returns all orders that have:
- at least 1 detail of category 13 *and*
- at least 1 detail of category 16 *and*
- at least 1 detail of category 66, 67, 68 or 69

Comment: It's possible that this would take even longer to run.  A true JOIN will scan the entire table to find all possible matches; WHERE EXISTS scans until it finds the first match and then evaluates to TRUE and moves on.  The original approach may already be the most efficient one, even if it seems like it takes a long time to run.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  As @tbrookside pointed, I used exists to avoid a full table scan, so using JOIN might not be a good alternative.

Comment: As stated before, I don't know how the tables are structured but I suppose you got an index on order_details.order_id (which should be a FK). In that case, no full table scan but an index scan